# How to use apply instead of loop to get averages from files across different directories

Tags: r, loops, apply, mean, lapply

I have written some code in 'R' using for loops, but wonder if anyone knows a better r 'apply' type of way? I will present my 'loop' solution below.

AIM - I have a number of tables (identically named) that are stored in directories named for a current month, the previous month, and the month before that also. They are stored in a directory called 'm1'. I need to calculate three month averages of the columns in these tables and write them back to csv files in the 'm3' directory.

The tables are related across the months through the 'key' column. The record sets have many similar keys across the months, but are not identical, so I use a 'merge' rather than an rbind.

The set up and some data...

```
set.seed(1234)

# dirs
if(!dir.exists("m1")){dir.create("m1")}
if(!dir.exists("m3")){dir.create("m3")}
if(!dir.exists("m1/201604")){dir.create("m1/201604")}
if(!dir.exists("m1/201605")){dir.create("m1/201605")}
if(!dir.exists("m1/201606")){dir.create("m1/201606")}

# objects
my_list = c("tbl_1", "tbl_2", "tbl_3")
month_list = c("201604", "201605", "201606")
my_files_paths = lapply(my_list, function(x) paste0("m1/", month_list, "/", x ,".csv"))

keys = replicate(100, paste0(sample(letters, 5), collapse = ""))


# some dummy data
# for 201604
tbl_1 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_abc = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_abc = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_1, "m1/201604/tbl_1.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_2 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_def = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_def = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_2, "m1/201604/tbl_2.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_3 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_ghi = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_ghi = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_3, "m1/201604/tbl_3.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")

# for 201605
tbl_1 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_abc = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_abc = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_1, "m1/201605/tbl_1.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_2 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_def = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_def = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_2, "m1/201605/tbl_2.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_3 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_ghi = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_ghi = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_3, "m1/201605/tbl_3.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")

# for 201606
tbl_1 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_abc = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_abc = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_1, "m1/201606/tbl_1.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_2 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_def = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_def = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_2, "m1/201606/tbl_2.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")
tbl_3 = data.frame(key = sample(keys, 90, replace = F), count_ghi = sample(1:10, 90, replace = T), amount_ghi = sample(1:30, 90, replace = T))
write.table(tbl_3, "m1/201606/tbl_3.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, sep = ",")


# I am trying to merge the 'same named csvs' from dirs '201604', '201605' and '201606'
# and get the averages for the "identical' columns in each month's dataframes

rm(month_list, my_list, tbl_1, tbl_2, tbl_3, keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# My 'loop' version answer... :)
# Does anyone have a better 'r/apply family' method

# NB - stringr needs to be installed


for(tbl in my_files_paths)
{

  # read the files in across the 3 months and merge
  my_tbl = lapply(tbl, function(x) read.table(x, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ","))
  merged.tbl = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "key", all = T), my_tbl)

  # set the key to rownames and remove the key column to leave only columns of interest
  row.names(merged.tbl) = merged.tbl$key
  merged.tbl$key = NULL

  # R appends '.x' and '.y' to duplicate column names, so these are cleaned off
  colnames(merged.tbl) = stringr::str_replace_all(colnames(merged.tbl), "\\.[a-z]", "")

  # unique column names are established to help subset
  col_names_merged_tbls = colnames(merged.tbl)
  col_names_merged_tbls = unique(col_names_merged_tbls)

  # subset the similar columns and derive the mean
  # store the means from each iteration in 'empty_vessel' and merge the results
  for(nme in col_names_merged_tbls)
  {
    sub_tbl = merged.tbl[, names(merged.tbl) == nme]
    sub_tbl[,1] = round(apply(sub_tbl, 1, mean, na.rm = T),2)
    sub_tbl = sub_tbl[,1, drop = F]
    # bring 'key' back into play to facilitate the merge
    sub_tbl$key = row.names(sub_tbl)
    if(!exists("empty_vessel")){empty_vessel <- list()}
    empty_vessel[[nme]] = sub_tbl

    new_tbl = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "key", all = T), empty_vessel)

  }
  rm(empty_vessel)

  # set the file_path up to write to
  file_path = stringr::str_replace_all(tbl[1], "m1/[0-9]*/", "")

  # write each new table with 3 month means to 'm3'
  write.table(new_tbl, paste0("m3/", file_path), sep = ",", col.names = T, row.names = F)

  # cleanup
  rm(col_names_merged_tbls, file_path, merged.tbl, my_tbl, new_tbl, nme, sub_tbl, tbl)

}

rm(my_files_paths)
```